# How to pass a property collection to Gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I would like to use the properties injection of command line Gradle to pass it an array, is this possible?

Something like this:

```
gradle build -PmyProp=['value1','value2','value3']
```

And access it like usual:

```
if(project.hasProperty('myProp')) {
    for ( prop in myProp ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot pass array as value of a property. However you can accept a comma separated string as value and split inside your gradle file.

```
if (project.hasProperty('myProp')) {
    project.properties['myProp'].split(',').each { 
        println it
    }
}
```

Run as `gradle build -PmyProp=value1,value2,value3`

Comment: This is a solution that I opted for in similar situation, with a minor difference that makes it cleaner, or rather "groovier" - I used Groovy's _tokenize_ method to split the parameters into a collection.

Answer (score 1):

`-Pmyprop=value` always gives a String value. You'd have to parse that String and turn it into a collection. Typically it's better to model common sets of arguments in the build script (e.g. by having a separate task per set of arguments).